# Shopify Page Loading Speed Hack?

Tags: shopify, pagespeed, lighthouse, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I hired someone from Upwork to help me increase our Shopify site loading speed from 10 on mobile and 60 on desktop and it magically increase to 90 on mobile and 98 on desktop. However, there were no significant changes on the Shopify site speed rating located on the Shopify dashboard itself.

I looked at the codes that were modified and I've found this code.

Can you let me know how to decipher this and let me know if this is scam/legit? Would highly appreciate it. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> const observer = new MutationObserver(e => { e.forEach(({ addedNodes: e }) => { e.forEach(e => { 1 === e.nodeType && "SCRIPT" === e.tagName && (e.innerHTML.includes("asyncLoad") && (e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace("if(window.attachEvent)", "document.addEventListener('asyncLazyLoad',function(event){asyncLoad();});if(window.attachEvent)").replaceAll(", asyncLoad", ", function(){}")), e.innerHTML.includes("PreviewBarInjector") && (e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace("DOMContentLoaded", "asyncLazyLoad")), (e.className == 'analytics') && (e.type = 'text/lazyload'),(e.src.includes("assets/storefront/features")||e.src.includes("assets/shopify_pay")||e.src.includes("connect.facebook.net"))&&(e.setAttribute("data-src", e.src), e.removeAttribute("src")))})})});observer.observe(document.documentElement,{childList:!0,subtree:!0})</script>{{ "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0603/7530/2276/t/1/assets/section.header.js" | script_tag}}
```

Before hiring from Fiverr, I tried to do the following steps:

- Minify CSS
- Optimized images
- Used "async" on our Javascript codes
- Removing unused apps

However, I'm not sure if those were properly implemented since there has been no significant changes on our lighthouse score.

Comment: Shopify backend also use the Google page insights as base to calculate the speed and done extra measures to determine the speed.

Comment: when you add products images and 3rd party apps it becomes much lower as compared to Google insights.

Comment: If your page loading is fast enought then I think you don't care about numbers much.

Comment: It looks like it is designed to alter scripts, so they don't run. There is probably some other code that changes them back so that they do run. How that code works could be a clue on why you get a good score. I've seen cases where the code does not fix the scripts if it detects that it is a speed test tool, so you get better scores.

Comment: Sometimes, a good score doesn't mean a good user experience. There are some techniques that defer all your content to run after google page speed has done its job so that you will get an excellent score but a very bad UX. It is considered a cheat to Google Page Speed. You can drop your store URL here so we can take a deeper look.

Comment: Last script is also designed to hack LCP (Largest Contentful Paint) Core Web Vital metric. It actually loads a very large but light and transparent image to make Lightouse believe LCP loads fast. It's discussed here: https://github.com/w3c/largest-contentful-paint/issues/72. It's kinda genuine hack but it may not last and may expose you to penalties, who knows. 90% of time these scripts target Google Lighthouse User Agents, which means that the gain in performance you see is just an illusion. As a devoted Shopify Partner it pains me to find such piece of code on merchants stores.